# Update value of HTML when input value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update a total when the value of one of the factors changes. I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aikaterine/dQKXt/)and provided a comment on it (line 16). This is probably the easiest place to see the issue.

It's simple sums, so I have a table that looks something like this.

```
Row 1  | 100 | 5 |
Row 2  | 200 | 10 |
Totals | 300 | 15 |
```

Table cells in Row 1 and Row 2 contain text fields. Table cells in the total row contain html. The id's and names of the div's / inputs are auto generated (please see jsFiddle link for example).

Everything works fine the first time I change the input amounts, but I am having a hard time setting the value of the original element to the new sum. When I update the field a second time, the calculation contemplates the original value - which throws my sums off. I have tried both the jQuery and javascript methods and have also tried with a specific id (not $(this)) all to no avail. I am new to javascript so am probably missing something simple.

My  javascript looks like this

```
window.formTable = $('#def-inv-table');
$('input.form-text').change(function() {
  var currentId      = $(this).attr('id');
  var orgValue       = this.getAttribute('value');
  var newValue       = this.value;
  var changeAmount   = newValue - orgValue;
  var pieces         = currentId.split(/\s*\-\s*/g);
  var key            = pieces[1];
  var orgTotalString = window.formTable.find('#total-' + pieces[2]).html();
  var orgTotal       = Number(orgTotalString.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
  var newTotal       = orgTotal + changeAmount;

  window.formTable.find('#total-' + pieces[2]).css("background", "blue");
  window.formTable.find('#total-' + pieces[2]).html(newTotal);

//Here is my problem. This is not updating. I have tried the javascript way
//with document.getElementbyId and the jQuery way. Neither sets the value.
  $(this).val(newValue);
  var testVal = $(this).val();
  //alert(testVal);
});
```

Please let me know if you want me to paste the html. I am leaving it out since it is in jsFiddle.

ADDING HTML

```
<form name="test-form" id="test-form">
  <div id="def-inv-table">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="no-413-invreturned" name="investments[413][invreturned]" value="3000.00" class="form-text">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="no-413-commreturned" name="investments[413][commreturned]" value="23.42" class="form-text">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="no-414-invreturned" name="investments[414][invreturned]" value="1000.00" class="form-text">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="no-414-commreturned" name="investments[414][commreturned]" value="15.89" class="form-text">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="total-invreturned">4,000.00</td>
        <td id="total-commreturned">39.31</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
<form>
```

Comment: You might want to include the HTML . . . jsFiddle gets blocked by some firewalls.

Comment: you use here `window.formTable.find('#total-' + pieces[2]).html(newTotal);` with `.html` method. Try using only `.val()` method calls

Comment: Sorry, there was an error in my explanation. I have edited the description. The total row contains html, not inputs.

Comment: @PeterThompson - the script is acting very weird - is it normal behaviour to update all the columns when changing one value on that row? Do you need a normal table which update the total values?

Comment: alex.dominte - the script only updates the total for that column. So if any value in column 1 changes, then the total row updates (same for column 2) I have checked jsFiddle and this is working as expected. The only problem I see (and I might be missing something) is that the sum is not correct when I change a value for the second time.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for but change `.change(` into `.keyup(`...

Comment: talemyn - thanks, will add html above

Comment: @PeterThompson - can you check the fiddle I just posted as answer, and let me know what is not working as you want on that fiddle and maybe I can change that one. or post a step-by-step example of what this script should do, like: update Table[0][0] = 100, update Table[0][1] = 1, etc

Comment: powtac - I tried to use `keyup()` originally but it produces weird results in the total column. Maybe because I am converting strings? Not sure, but I had to use `change()` in order for it to even come close to working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/dQKXt/86/

```
$('.form-text').change(function() {
    var columnIndex = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    var sum = 0;
    $('tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + ')').find('input').each(function() {
        var floatValue = parseFloat($(this).val());
        $(this).val(floatValue.toFixed(2));
        sum += floatValue;        
    });    

    // here format your sum with , . etc to be the same as 4,000.00
    $('tr td:nth-child(' + columnIndex + '):last').html(sum.toFixed(2));

});
```

Assuming you want a normal table with sum row

Comment: alex.dominte - thank you for the help. It is doing exactly what I needed. Please also let me know if I need to do anything other than check your answer to finish off this question. Now I just need to study your code to see what I should have done in the beginning.

Comment: @PeterThompson - your welcome. yes, accepting an aswers should do the job. you let know for the others your problem was fixed